# How to read the primary key of a ForeignKey without loading the corresponding item?

Tags: django, models

I have 2 Django models :

```
class A(models.Model):
    uniq_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,primary_key=True)
    info1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)     
    info2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    info3 = models.CharField(max_length=30)     
    info4 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

If I do :

```
b = B.objects.get(id = n), it generates one database request.
```

If I do

```
print b.a.pk : it generate another request.
```

Is that possible to access b.a primary key (I only need this information, not info1 nor info2) without generating another request nor using 'select_related()' ?

I could do a :

```
print b.__dict__['a_id']
```

It works, but it seems to me very ugly : do you have a nicer way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to go via the dict: `b.a_id` works fine.

Comment: That is very important in my case, because I need to load the related row with FOR UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

No. [That's how it's done](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this dynamically (like I did):

```
related_field = 'a'
related_id = getattr(obj, f'{related_field}_{A._meta.pk.name}')
```